# Force version of dependency in gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Is it possible to force gradle to use a different dependency in a plugin?

I want to run the openapi-generator 5.1.1 plugin, but I want it to use swagger-parser 2.0.26. The reason for this is the issue mentioned below. In that issue, the user "selliera" mentions he was able to run the plugin with that dependency (ok, he mentions 2.0.20, but the unreleased fix uses 2.0.26).

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8266

I have tried using a strict version:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser") {
        version {
            strictly "2.0.26"
        }
    }
}
```

And using

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'io.swagger.parser.v3' && details.requested.name =='swagger-parser') {
                details.useVersion("2.0.26")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But neither seems to have any effect.

Here's a simple gradle script to demonstrate the issue. If you place the [contents of the petstore spec](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.yaml) in the petstore.yml file specified in the script below and run `openApiGenerate`, it works fine. If you change the url in the petstore spec to a relative one (like in the linked issue), the generator fails. Using the new version of swagger-parser is supposed to fix this.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '5.1.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = 'spring'
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/petstore.yml"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me (gradle 5.6.4):

- To force a dependency version of a **plugin**, add this to the top of your build.gradle script (before the `plugins {}` block):

```
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser:2.0.26'
        }
    }
}
```

- Just for clarification, if you add a similar configuration outside of the `buildscript {}` block, it will force a dependency version of your **application** instead:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser:2.0.26'
    }
}
```

PS: By now swagger-parser 2.0.26 is a default for openapi-generator 5.4.0

PPS: I know, it's an old question, but still top in Google

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question! I am no longer at the assignment where I had this problem, so I needed some time to reproduce it. But I can confirm your solution works! I have updated my original question to also include an example gradle script to demonstrate the issue I was having.

Comment: How would this look like in Gradle 8 or later?