# Specify version of dependency of Gradle AsciidoctorJ Plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, asciidoctor

I'm trying to achieve in Gradle 8.1.1 what you would do like this in Maven:

```xml
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
          <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
              <artifactId>jruby</artifactId>
              <version>9.4.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

I tried several things. However, I'm at my wits end. Here is my current build.gradle file:

```
import org.asciidoctor.gradle.jvm.AsciidoctorTask
import org.asciidoctor.gradle.jvm.pdf.AsciidoctorPdfTask


buildscript {
    configurations {
        classpath {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force("org.jruby:jruby-complete:9.4.5.0")
            }
        }
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert' version "${asciidoctorVersion}"
    id 'org.asciidoctor.jvm.pdf' version "${asciidoctorVersion}"
}

configurations {

    pluginTool {
        defaultDependencies { dependencies ->
            dependencies.add(this.dependencies.create("org.jruby:jruby-complete:9.4.5.0"))
        }
    }

    implementation {
        withDependencies { DependencySet dependencies ->
            ExternalModuleDependency dep = dependencies.find { it.name == 'jruby-complete' } as ExternalModuleDependency
            dep.version {
                strictly "9.4.5.0"
            }
        }
    }

    userManual {
        canBeConsumed = true
        canBeResolved = false
    }
}

asciidoctorj {
    fatalWarnings missingIncludes()

    version '2.5.10'

    modules {
        diagram.use()
        diagram.version '2.2.13'
        pdf.version '2.3.9'
    }

    attributes = [
            'build-gradle': file('build.gradle'),
            'author'      : 'abc',
            'revnumber'   : project.version,
    ]
}
```

I want the plugin to use a newer jruby-version in order to fix this bug here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin/issues/553

Similar stuff has been discussed here: [Force version of dependency in gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874881/force-version-of-dependency-in-gradle-plugin)

Have no clue how to verify which dependency is actually used. The bug, however is still there and several versions of jruby are in my dependency-verification.xml.